# PHP - Check given date is in future over 20 years using PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime, floor

I want to check whether given date is over 20 years in future using PHP

So far I'm doing this:

```
<?php
$date = '2039-03-23';
if (floor((time() + strtotime($date)) / (60*60*24*365)) > 20)
{
    echo "date is in future over 20 years..<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "date is in future but less than 20 years.<br>";
}
```

But it is not working, can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly the [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) if you're on a 32bit system; try using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead.

Comment: I hope I'm not alive by then. I don't want to fix decades old code :( Was bad enough during y2k ;)

Comment: For any date(today, next year date etc.) it is printing the message **date is in future over 20 years..**

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the date of now (`time()`) to `$date`, and end way farther in futur than intended, so instead :

```
floor((strtotime($date)-time()) / (60*60*24*365))
```

Should give you the difference between 2039-03-23 and now.

Note that you can have dates inferior to today and you should maybe consider adding a "date is in the past" result.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer of Nomis is correct, your aproach looks terribly complicated and ugly. I'd make use of the `DateTime`-Object and work with those:

```
//create the DateTime-Object with origin time
$dateOrigin = new DateTime('2027-03-23');
//create a new one with current time
$dateNow = new DateTime();
//Add 20 years to the current time object
$dateNow->add(new DateInterval("P240M"));

//compare them
if($dateNow < $dateOrigin) {
  echo "date is 20 or more years in the future";
} else {
  echo "date is not 20 or more years in the future";
}
```

Working [example](https://repl.it/repls/GrowlingEnormousCircles).

Comment: Yup, way more reliable and nicer, but a little more complex to learn. Your answer is the way to go for serious works.

Comment: Thanks, it works and using DateTime() object is nice way to work with dates.

Comment: @Nomis Indeed, it's a bit more complex, but I think it's never too early to start working with classes.